# React Google Gantt Chart not changing styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-charts

I am working on a react component that utilizes a react-google-chart in the Gantt format. The Chart is the one shown below.

```
<Chart
      width={'100%'}
      height={'400px'}
      chartType="Gantt"
      loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
      data={grafico}
      options={{
        height: 400,
        gantt: {
          trackHeight: 30,
          labelStyle: {
            fontName: 'Arial',
            fontSize: 14    ,
            color: 'white'
          },
          percentEnabled: false,
        },
        backgroundColor: {
            fill: '#1B1B1B'
        },
        
      }}
    />
```

Although the labelStyle.color is set to white, none of the colors from the Gantt chart are white.

What could be the issue? Thanks in advance.

I tried using ChatGPT for help, but I probably am not giving the right prompt. Also, I tried searching in the Google Charts library, but I don't seem to be doing anything wrong based on that.